# Traditional looking toggle switch that works with Hue (possibly through Alexa/google)?

Tags: smart-home, alexa, google-home, philips-hue

New to this Hue madness, got a 4 pack with Hub. Enjoying the lights, not ready to start asking Google/Alexa to turn on my lights.

I know Philips has a couple switches, but Im looking for something more traditional (below). I haven't found any toggles that seem to work directly with the Hue. Are there any that will connect to Google Home or Alexa (or other) that can then be linked to the Hue? Sort of like daisy chaining the switch, through Google/other, and then control the lights.

Any suggestions welcome. Thank you!

[image]

UPDATE: Ive also found this RunLessWire Hue Switch, which appears to have a exchangeable faceplate, which would meet my overall look desire.

**CON:** Pricey AF

[image]

Comment: @hardillb its an update, I dont consider my question answered at this point. Appreciate your insight into solutions as well.

Comment: But it's an update that doesn't add any value to anybody else as we have no idea where you found it.

Comment: @hardillb and now you have caused us both to have a discussion in comments which is even worse than anything to begin with. Im glad we are having fun. But yes, I do agree and didnt see earlier that I didnt indicate where that switch came from.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there are quite a few switches under the [Friends of Hue](https://www2.meethue.com/en-gb/friends-of-hue/switches) range which have exactly the style you're looking for, instead of the more unusual switches like [this one](https://www2.meethue.com/en-gb/p/hue-dimmer-switch/8718696743157) in the Hue range.

Particularly you might be interested in the following:

- the [Niko dimmer switch](https://www.dmlights.co.uk/niko_120_91004_white~171M1)
- the [Vimar Plana switch](https://www.vimar.com/en/int/catalog/product/index/code/0K03906.02)
- the range from [Busch-Jaeger](https://www.busch-jaeger.de/en/products/product-solutions/remote-control/friendsofhue/) marketed under the Friends of Hue range

The Friends of Hue logo means that Philips has tested and certified a specific accessory to be compatible with their Hue range.
It seems that it's a little difficult to find sellers for some of the Friends of Hue switches but it may be worth trying, given that they do have that certification from Philips.

Comment: Very close, looking for a single profile - but thanks for the lead. I looked for quite some time and never came across any of these.